# How to enable the Alt + right click shortcut (select edge loop) in Lubuntu?

Tags: modeling, shortcut, linux

On Lubuntu the shorcut Alt + right click moves the entire Blender window instead of selecting edge loops in edit mode. How do i disable the Linux shortcut to use it with Blender.

Comment: I always just used the shift modifier with a-key to clear the selection...I'm not on Linux any more, but that worked great for me a year or two ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the shortcut on Lubuntu open the file manager and at the path line copy and past this: `~/.config/openbox/`
Open the file `lubuntu-rc.xml` (you can use Leafpad) and delete the following lines:

> ```
>   <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Press">
>     <action name="Focus"/>
>     <action name="Raise"/>
>     <action name="Unshade"/>
>   </mousebind>
>   <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Drag">
>     <action name="Resize"/>
>   </mousebind>
> ```

Then save the file, open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type this:

```
sudo openbox --restart
```